# ASP.NET WebAPI deserializing DTO alternative/old property names

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

We have an ASP.Net WebAPI (v5.2.2) application and use and a DTO object with a couple of fields for a method.
We want to change the field name but alot of old clients still use the old DTO filed name.

What I am looking for is recommendations about the best way to "rewrite" property X to Y when deserializing if encountered but when serializing Y it should work as usual.

Somthing like a DataMember-ButAlsoDeserializeFrom("X")-Attribute kind of thing.
Any ideas?

Comment: See [Making a property deserialize but not serialize with json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11564091/10263) for some ideas.

Comment: I solved it by adding this code. 

[DataMember]
internal string OldPropName { set { this.NewPropName = value; } }