# Newtonsoft Json.NET do not serialize [Obsolete] property

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there a way to configure Json.NET to not serialize properties which have an `[Obsolete]` attribute?

e.g.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Obsolete]
    public int Age { get; set; }
 }

 var foo = new Foo { Id = 123, Age = 23 };
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
```

In the above example, the json is `{"Id":123,"Age":23}`

I would like `{"Id":123}`

Comment: Do any of the answers from [Making a property deserialize but not serialize with json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11564091) meet your needs?

Comment: Can't you simply add also [JsonIgnore] attribute ?

Comment: @SteveB unfortunately I don't have control over the `Foo` class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use a custom [`ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) to exclude properties marked obsolete.
Here is the code you would need for the resolver:

```
public class ExcludeObsoletePropertiesResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (prop.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(true).OfType<ObsoleteAttribute>().Any())
        {
            prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => false;
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new ExcludeObsoletePropertiesResolver()
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
```

Working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gIRCD4

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the fiddle!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to override the method that collects the members to be serialized and filtering out the members there?

`protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
 {
            var members =  base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);
            members.RemoveAll(m => m.IsDefined(typeof(ObsoleteAttribute), true));
            return members;
  }`

Comment: @SindriJóelsson Depends what you are trying to do I guess.  If you want to be able to exclude the members while serializing, but still allow them to be deserialized into (which seems like it might be desirable for an `[Obsolete]` property), then you should not filter out the members, but instead set up the `ShouldSerialize` predicate as shown in my answer.  If you want to exclude them both ways, then filtering them out is one way to do that.  Another way is to set `Ignored = true` on the properties.

Comment: @BrianRogers, I realized that after posting my answer. When I was implementing this for my use case the obsolete members would throw exceptions when accessed or set.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise conditional serialisation as documented here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm

If you have control over the class and want to target specific properties you know upfront it would be easier to use the first mechanism, offering `ShouldSerializeAge()` method

But most probably it seems you need something generic in this case you can create a `IContractResolver` class that uses Reflection to check whether a given property has the `Obselete` attribute

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have control over the class in question.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Brian Rogers' answer: It's a little bit simpler/faster to filter out the members to exclude in an override of `GetSerializableMembers()` method rather than the `CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)` which gets called for on each `MemberInfo` returned by `GetSerializedMembers()` to avoid unnecessary calls to the CreateProperty method which does a bunch of reflection and delegate creation.

```
public class ExcludeObsoletePropertiesResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        var members =  base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);
        members.RemoveAll(m => m.IsDefined(typeof(ObsoleteAttribute), true));
        return members;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new ExcludeObsoletePropertiesResolver()
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
```

Comment: Ooh this looks nice and clean