# JSON different serialization from deserialization in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am using JSON.NET to deserialize and serialize JSON. I would like to ignore some fields but only during serialization and not deserializing, somthing like `[JsonIgnoreWhenSerializing]`, does this exist or is there any way to do this?

Comment: There's no `access` property on `JsonPropertyAttribute`, and the `@` syntax, are you confusing this question for Java?

Comment: Add a `ShouldSerializePropertyName` method alongside the property, that returns `false`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen you are probably right.maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564091/making-a-property-deserialize-but-not-serialize-with-json-net) will help him

Comment: Yes, that is better duplicate question.