# jsonignore attribute also ignores property in payload

Tags: javascript, c#, rest, web

In C# I use the `jsonignore` attributes for some calculated properties on various classes. This works fine when serializing the objects to the database and deserializing them from the database again. The properties are not part of the data. But on the client-side (JavaScript) I would like to include the these properties in the payload from the server, but they are not part of it because of the attribute. Is there any way I can exclude properties from being saved to the database but still being part on the JSON payload returned to the client?

Comment: If you separate your View and Data Models you can achieve what you want to do.

Comment: thanks, I know. I was just thinking if there was an easier way to accomplish the same.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564091/making-a-property-deserialize-but-not-serialize-with-json-net