# Updating the name of a Json Property in a class

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

I am trying to update the name of a property in a Json serializable class that is already released, so I need to make it backwards compatible.

```
public class myClass
{
    //[JsonIgnore] - now old json files can't be read, so this won't work...
    //[JsonProperty(ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Error)] - didn't do anything
    //[JsonProperty(nameof(NewName)] - throws error - "That already exists"
    [Obselete("Use NewName instead")]
    public List<string> OldName { get => newName; set => newName = value; }

    public List<string> NewName { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
[Test]
public void test()
{
    var foo = new myClass()
    {
        OldName = { "test" },
    };

    var bar = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(bar, typeof(myClass));
}
```

When I look at the value in result.NewName, I find this list: `{"test", "test"}`, but I expected this list: `{"test"}`

The desired behavior:

- If someone is already using OldName in their code, they get an obselete warning
- if someone parses an old json file with OldName in it, it's correctly mapped to NewName
- New json files that are created use NewName, and OldName isn't found anywhere in the json file
- In no case is the value deserialized twice and put in the same list

How would you accomplish this?

Comment: I would create custom converter for this type.

Comment: putting [JsonProperty(ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)] over both OldName and NewName prevents it from appending to the list, but doesn't stop duplicated properties in the Json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24224465/5617177) was very helpful. Basically you refactor your code like this:

```
public class ControlReportResult : TargetReportResult
{
    public List<string> NewName { get; set; } = new();

    [JsonIgnore] // this stops the serializer from paying attention to this property
    [Obsolete("Use NewName instead")]
    public List<string> OldName => { get => NewName; set => NewName = value; }
    
    [JsonProperty("OldName")] //This doesn't throw an error because the serializer was told to ignore the real OldName property
    private List<string> _jsonOldNameSetter { set => NewName = value; } // no getter, so we are never going to write OldName out.
}
```

Some notes:

- _jsonOldNameSetter is private, so your interface is still clean
- OldName is still usable, but marked as obselete
- The code will read in json files with **either** OldName or NewName, but will only write files with NewName

It shouldn't happen, but if you still somehow end up with a json file with **both** an OldName and a NewName, add the attribute `[JsonProperty(ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)]` above OldName and NewName - this way they will overwrite each other, rather than appending.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var foo = "{\"OldName\":[\"old test\"]}";
var fooN = "{\"NewName\":[\"new test\"]}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(foo, typeof(myClass));
//or
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fooN, typeof(myClass));

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

json result:

```
{"NewName":["new test"]}
//or
{"NewName":["old test"]}
```

class

```
public class myClass
{
   [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<string> OldName {

        get {return null; }
        set {NewName=value;} 
    }

    public List<string> NewName {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Fancy! Unfortunately in my case, I still need to allow people to have get access to the OldName property for now. But I'm sure you're answer will help others! Thanks for looking at it!

Answer (score 0):

This works using System.Text.Json.

```
            var foo = new myClass()
            {
                OldName = { "test" },
            };

            var bar = JsonSerializer.Serialize<myClass>(foo);
            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<myClass>(bar);
```

Comment: But the json string contains both values: {"OldName":["test","test2"],"NewName":["test","test2"]}. The deserializer may use an "append" mode for json array. That may explain that when OldName is deserialized, OldName has 2 values set (and so NewName), then the deserializer read NewName and append the 2 values from the json into the already 2 values of the List coming from OldName.

Comment: True. I wonder if putting  [JsonProperty(ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)] over the properties would stop them from appending.