# .NET Newtonsoft JSON serialization: Ignore static (abstract) attribute

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, json.net

Problem: Static class members are being serialized when they actually should not.

Note that I have the **preview features activated** which enables me to use [static abstract attributes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/static-abstracts-in-interfaces.md) in interfaces. To have Newtonsoft ignore any fields/properties when serializing, I use a self-defined attribute taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564091/making-a-property-deserialize-but-not-serialize-with-json-net):

```c#
public class JsonIgnoreSerializationAttribute : Attribute { }
class JsonPropertiesResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        //Return properties that do NOT have the JsonIgnoreSerializationAttribute
        return objectType.GetProperties()
                         .Where(pi => !Attribute.IsDefined(pi, typeof(JsonIgnoreSerializationAttribute)))
                         .ToList<MemberInfo>();
    }
}
```

This the interface, simplified for the sake of illustration:

```c#
public interface IApiObject
{
    public string ApiObjectId { get; set; }

    static abstract string ObjectName { get; }
}
```

Now I have a class ApiObject implementing the interface:

```c#
 public abstract class ApiObject : IApiObject
 {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "api_object_id")]
    [JsonIgnoreSerialization]
    public string? ApiObjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnoreSerialization]
    public static string ObjectName { get; }
 }
```

In reality there are many more fields, but when serializing, regular members marked with this attribute are being ignored while static members are not - they are being serialized which I actually want to avoid because it causes errors on the API.

Serialization:

```c#
 jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(batch, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new JsonPropertiesResolver() });
```

I wonder if this is

- a bug or
- Newtonsoft is just not supporting the preview feature
- or me not understanding/seeing something very obvious

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying that `[JsonIgnore]` doesn't work so you had to create your own attribute?

Comment: [JsonIgnore] works only for deserialization, at least for me. In fact, I use that decorator as well. [JsonIgnore] [NotMapped] [JsonIgnoreSerialization]

Comment: *[JsonIgnore] works only for deserialization, at least for me.* -- can you share a [mcve] reproducing that?

Comment: It seems you took `JsonPropertiesResolver` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35234883/3744182) by [Jraco11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3174275/jraco11), but this contract resolver is broken precisely because it ignores `JsonIgnoreAttribute`.

Comment: To fix it, use `base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType).Where(pi => !Attribute.IsDefined(pi, typeof(JsonIgnoreSerializationAttribute))).ToList();` as shown in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564091/making-a-property-deserialize-but-not-serialize-with-json-net#comment61914098_35234883) by [Alain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529618/alain)

Comment: Does fixing `JsonPropertiesResolver` and applying `[JsonIgnore]` fix your problem?

Comment: Thanks everybody, especially @dbc, whose suggestion solved the issue for me!